# SQL - Return no row if JOIN works

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, not-exists

I have a typical SQL statement with an `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT * from t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.a = t1.a
```

My requirement is, that the result set should be empty, if the join returns at least 1 row. If the join returns 0 rows, then I would like to see the results.

First, I thought of using `NOT EXISTS` (or `LEFT JOIN` + `IS NULL`), but this does not work in my case, because with this I would return results if nothing is found in the other table which is not what I need. I want to return nothing, if there is a match in the other table and I want to return something, if there is no match in the other table.

Comment: If the join returns 0 rows, then which results do you want to show?  Not my downvote, but your question does not make a lot of sense.

Comment: Do you mean an `left outer join `?

Comment: Your question is a bit contradicting but I assume you just want to do something when the result returns 0 rows?

1. Declare a variable (e.g joinRowCount)
2. Place the count of the select inside the variable
3. If your variable = 0  --> do stuff Else --> don't do stuff

Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a CASE and EXISTS statement:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.a = t1.a)
       THEN 0
       ELSE 1 
       END
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

SELECT * from t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.a = t1.a where t2.a is null

Hope this help you

Comment: select 1 as a,2 as b
into #temp1

insert into #temp1
select 2 as a,3 as b

select 3 as a,2 as b
into #temp2

insert into #temp2
select 4 as a,3 as b

select * from #temp1 t1,
#temp2 t2
where 0 =
(SELECT count(*) from #temp1 t1
INNER JOIN #temp2 t2 ON  t2.a = t1.a )

Answer (score -1):

As far I can understand the problem(correct if I am wrong), you need  all "a" column of table t1 when join returns no rows and null when join returns atleast 1 row.

Below query in oracle will result in :

1)  null if join return atleast one row

2)  concatenated values of column "a" of table t1 if join return no rows
note :  instead of wm_concat, listagg can be used depending on version.

select
(case
when join_count > 0  then null

else (select to_char(wm_concat(a)) from t1)

end)
"result"

from
(select count(col1) as 'join_count' from (select t1.a as 'col1' from t1 join t2 on t1.a=t2.a));